# Problem running Android Studio from VSCode

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, ionic5

Trying to learn Ionic and when I try to open the generated android app from vs code with the command

npx cap open android

but when I use the npx cap run android everything works

Is my problem in Android Studio or in VSCodes when I get this problem and what do I need to do??
[image]

Hope to make Android Studio start from VSCode

Comment: you want to start android studio from vscode or android emulator from vscode?

Comment: I want Android studio to start. Emulator work like it should